# Code Analysis CA1307 & CA1310 not working in new .NET 6 projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-6.0, roslyn

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (17.4.4), and when I create a new empty .NET 6 project, Code Analysis doesn't work.

[According to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/install-net-analyzers?view=vs-2022), Roslyn Code Analyzers are automatically enabled for every new .NET 6 project:

> Starting in Visual Studio 2019 16.8 and .NET 5.0, these analyzers are
> included with the .NET SDK. Analysis is enabled, by default, for
> projects that target .NET 5.0 or later.

Here's the steps I followed:

1. Start Visual Studio
2. Create a new .NET 6 Console Project
3. Paste the code below
4. Click Analyze -> Run Code Analysis. I would expect to get CA1307 or CA1310 - however, I get neither.

How can I get Code Analysis to work here?

```
Console.WriteLine("asdf".IndexOf("/")); // expecting CA1307 or CA1310 here
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 5.0 `CA1307` is `Disabled` and `CA13010` is `Hidden` you can have a complete view of Roslyn rules [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/NetAnalyzers/Core/AnalyzerReleases.Shipped.md)